# Microsoft Access date comparison in query not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I added the following field in a query:

```
IIf(Date()<[NextQDue],"Less","Greater")
```

The field NextQDue was created in a different query and formatted as Short Date. The value in NextQDue is 12/20/2018. Today's date is 1/1/2019. The query spits out "Less" when it should spit out "Greater." If I change the statement to Date()>[NextQDue] it spits out "Greater" when it should say "Less." I cannot figure this out. I believe I've formatted dates correctly, but nothing is working.

Comment: Is CDate available? Does it work if you use `Date()<CDate([NextQDue])`?

Comment: It's giving me a datatype mismatch when I do that. I'm going to look more into what CDate does.

Comment: Your original expression works for me. Formatted how, with Format() function? Format function results in a string value, not a true date. However, CDate() should force it back to a date value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always handle dates as *Date*, not text, not numbers, no exceptions.

So, adjust your query and change `NextQDue` to return a true date value.

If you need to display the value of `NextQDue` somewhere else, apply the format to the control displaying it.

Comment: That did the trick. I created NextQDue using DateSerial (because I was combining three different values to make a date). Before I was just formatting three values to make it appear to be a date. I honestly didn't know that using Format doesn't create a date, it creates a string that appears as a date to the user. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.